# How can I recover my Transcend pendrive when both the  used space and free space are 0 bytes?

Tags: windows-xp, usb-storage

I have an Transcend pendrive, and when I connect it and double click it to explore, it is showing the error:

> Please insert a disk into drive

Also In the properties field it is showing

> File system- Unknown
>   Used space- 0 bytes
>   free space- 0 bytes
>   capacity- 0 bytes

I tried to format it using using the command prompt but it is not showing in the `list disk` command.  It is also not showing in the Disk Management.

Comment: Does anything show up in `Device Manager`? Do you get the "bee-boop" sound? Do other devices connected to the same USB port work? (And, by the way, it should be impossible for a pen drive to show in explorer without showing up in Disk Management. What shows up on explorer exactly?)

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully there is a way to fix it. I do the following steps and recovered my usb drive.
you need to determine flash chip provider in the following way then download the utility:

> 1- download chipgui 3 to detect ur chip provider,vid and pid
>   https://sites.google.com/site/future81/ChipGenius.rar
>
> 2- connect ur flash only
>
> 3-look for ur flash name in the listed usb devices in the program and
>   click it
>
> 4-enter russian site http://www.flashboot.ru
>
> 5-click iflash and enter vid and pid of ur flash and click button next
>   to it
>
> 6-the site will show u a list, try to locate the entry that have same
>   name(e.g dt 101) and same chip vendor – chip part number(located to
>   the right of pid vid) returned from chip gui program if applicable and
>   locate same size(not very important – the same chip program can repair
>   different sizes in most cases) when u find ur flash entry note the
>   name of the utilty to repair it in last column
>
> 7- click the menu left of iflash
>
> 8- click ur chip provider from left list
>
> 9- locate the utilty u got from step 6 click it and click button at
>   bottom – enter code and download
>
> 10- if utility is true it shoud detect ur drive and repair /format it
>   sometimes chip provider supplied by chipgui maybe incorrect ,if so do
>   the following:
>
> 1-in iflash list locate chip providers and try to download last
>   version of utility for each
>
> 2-try utility see if it recognized ur flash or not ,the one that does
>   may be providing the info u need like (card info button) in
>   SSS_MP_Utility_v2173 from sss chip provider -take ur part number and
>   return to iflash list to locate the right tool for ur flsh version –
>   for SSS_MP_Utility_v2173 u can save card info to file – note isp
>   version – locate bin file that have same isp version in isp code
>   directory -copy its name to ini file in the root program directory and
>   also redefine provider vif pid in that ini according to info u read
>   put u must convert hexadecimal vid pid to decimal through windows
>   calculator and type decimal values in the ini- u can make a copy of
>   ini and name it as u want
>
> 3- start program again and choose ur ini and flash ur disk

Alernatively you can see the response number 101 in the post [usb-drive-unusable-unformattable-and-reporting-0-bytes-capacity](http://www.ardamis.com/2009/07/02/usb-drive-unusable-unformattable-and-reporting-0-bytes-capacity/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't; the controller is damaged. Stick it in the circular file.

Answer (score 0):

If this continues even when you plug it into other computers, the problem is most likely the USB pen itself. USB units are very prone to electrical errors, so it seems very likely that it's no longer reacting the way it should. And that it never will...